# How can I use literal HTML in a CoffeeKup template?

Tags: javascript, templates, node.js, coffeescript, coffeekup

I'm becoming a huge fan of CoffeeKup, but I'm wondering how I can use literal HTML in such a template? For example when I just want to copy-paste some existing, non-CoffeeKup markup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add arbitrary text with the `text` function:

```
text '<p>foo</p>'
```

For multiline strings, CoffeeScript's heredocs are a pleasure:

```
text '''
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Foo</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
'''
```

Just make sure you have `autoescape` set to `false` (the default value).

Comment: You're welcome! I also started working on a CoffeeKup [reference](https://github.com/mauricemach/coffeekup/blob/master/docs/reference.md) if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using this tool too for converting your markup instead of just inlining in?

https://github.com/brandonbloom/html2coffeekup

It's linked from the main github page of coffeekup. If it handles your old markup it would be a more elegant solution.